# How can I change the color of left edge of box

Tags: html, css

I want to make the box with left color bar like this

[image]

At first I should use the border-left property and change the color of one edge of the box.

However the boundary of each edge will not be 90 degree 45 degree.

How can I make this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the boundary of each edge will not be 90 degree 45 degree"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point, feel free to add additional details in the comments, because it's a bit hard to understand what you're after.

```css
.example {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F7F8F8;
  border-left: 6px #FE2A45 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```